# Android: How to store my recent searches and display in the app

Tags: android, android-widget, android-sqlite

I'm building an app which helps in searching just like Google's search widget. In my app I have an auto-suggest which brings the typed data from wiki-suggest URL in json format. I'm able to populate it, but I want to know that how can I save my recent searches and display it on the app, just like Google's search widget do. I don't have any idea about this. Any suggestion or tweak will be helpful at this point.

Can I do one thing, typed query after pressing search button, save it simultaneously in the database or something and again if user comes back then I can populate the string in the app. Is that possible? 
If yes, can some point me to how to store and retrieve string from the SQLite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SQLite to store the search keys in a table along with a column for the time they were searched for.  You could then access the most recent searches by limiting by time.  A google search for SQLite Android will return a lot of resources on this issue.  This tutorial might be useful to start: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But again I have a doubt, I just have to store a string and display it. So, should I use shared preferences or SQLite? I could not figure it out. I want to make my app simple and easy to use, should not be heavy weight.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either a file you write or use SharedPreferences to store data outside off your app lifecycle: [SharedPreferenes | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But again I have a doubt, I just have to store a string and display it. So, should I use shared preferences or SQLite? I could not figure it out. I want to make my app simple and easy to use, should not be heavy weight.

Comment: Most developers trust SharedPreferences. SQLlite is too much for a simple String.

Comment: Ok will go with shared preferences only.

Comment: Can you guide me to some examples for dynamically adding strings into shared prefernces?

Comment: private SharedPreferences sp;
sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.edit().putString("key","value").commit();